# Revert from Managed to Unmanaged Package

Tags: managed-package, package, unmanaged-package

Is it currently possible to **revert back** from **managed** package **to unmanaged**? It was my first time trying to make a managed package and I noticed it affected all the objects' api names and caused much trouble for us especially on the codes. I already tried searching for it but most related posts are kinda old or unanswered. Can anyone please **share** your ideas / experiences with this matter? Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it is not possible to go from managed to unmanaged package.You need to copy all your code to a new org without a suffix.